# Alter a column on 4M+ entries table running on production

Tags: mysql, server

I'm trying to add a column on a 4M+ entries table running on production using `phpmyadmin`

Here is what happens on `mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` :

```
Query   |  670 | copy to tmp table               | ALTER TABLE `table_name`  ADD `new_column` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL  AFTER `other_column`

Sleep   |  671 |                                 | NULL

[... And here all inserts attempts to that table are stacking ...]
```

It crashes after 13 minutes:

```
200509  0:44:41  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 71728461312
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 71733704192
[...]
```

How can I add that column... :(

Comment: what mysql version? Show the full error log that shows before the crash, Its possible that you have told mysql about more memory than you have. What is your my.cnf and other mysql config?

Comment: @danblack It seems to be version 5.5.54. Here are directly all the variables : https://pastebin.com/KTRzUYRt Sadly there is no error log before the crash.

Comment: lack of log normally indicates a hard kill, either kill -9 or more likely, you ran out of memory. If you run `dmesg` on the OS you may see it killed. I see you have 14G of innodb buffer pool, do you actually have the hardware RAM to support this? Welcome to SO, [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better forum for pure DB questions however. [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) can help change a table structure while still active.

Comment: true, `dmesg` output: `Out of memory: Kill process 3749 (mysqld) score 432 or sacrifice child
Killed process 3749 (mysqld) total-vm:16898796kB, anon-rss:6873164kB, file-rss:0kB
init: mysql main process (3749) killed by KILL signal
init: mysql main process ended, respawning
init: mysql post-start process (13375) terminated with status 1` There is 16GB RAM

Comment: @danblack Is there an option without `pt-online-schema-change` or manual copy/paste of table ? How did it run out of memory ? Is there a way to prevent it while still making the change ?

Comment: pt-online-schema-change automates the copying of data, but ultimately lowering the innodb_buffer_pool_size is needed to prevent OOM. Once you've done that, wait for a day of uptime and ask for tuning advice on DBA Exchange. Configuration file contents while not the complete settings, and omit runtime changes, are easier to read the substantial differences from the default configuration. Good to see you increased the innodb_log_file size. They all look quite big but maybe that matches your workload.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't imagine that VARCHAR(1) is useful (as opposed to, say, CHAR(1) ), but I'd be happy to be proven wrong

Answer (score 1):

Too much memory was allocated to innodb_buffer_pool_size compared to the 16G present, but the remaining 2G was also used.

Connections use a certain amount of memory. An `ALTER TABLE` locks the table rom inserts so the inserts queue up, using more memory. The alter table use a reasonable amount of memory.

Reducing the buffer pool size down to 10G or so might give enough available ram. Look a [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/) results which so RAM calculations. Wait until the service is up for a day or so before looking at other recommendations.

Comment: 1/ The 13GB size was set after the recommendation of `mysqltuner`, that 13GB is the maximum memory usage that all queries included can take at the same time, right ? 2/ So mysql shouldn't take more alone ? 3/ How do you explain that on my local machine with a smaller RAM, the change took a few minutes on the same table but with ~2M5 rows while it ran out of memory after 13 minutes on the remote server? 4/ If I reduce to 10G and try to alter the column again, will it still take 15min+ ? Maybe 30? Thank you.

Comment: I assume 13 minutes was because it was aggressively swapping to try to get it done before it failed. The alter table doesn't significantly use the innodb buffer pool to enact changes so I would expect it to be quicker, since it has the RAM to do what it needs to. Later mysql versions could actually change this setting without a restart.

Comment: This time I got `200509  2:30:15  InnoDB: Error: Write to file ./ibdata1 failed at offset 3 1137704960.
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 98304 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.`

Comment: `InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
200509  2:30:16 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: La table '#sql-6f4b_19b' est pleine
200509  2:30:17 [ERROR] Error writing file '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log' (errno: 28)`

Comment: `perror 28`
OS error code  28:  No space left on device

Comment: an `ALTER TABLE` copies the entire table and then replaces the original. Space is required.

Comment: damn man I thought I lost my db x) it's still alive... damn why does it copy on `/var/log` where the disk has `20gb` and ib_data already takes `14G` while there is `2 To` available on the other disk

Comment: `tmpdir` is used for table alterations. Your `/var/log` might be full also.

Comment: `tmpdir` is in that same `/dev/root ` partition (20Gb) which is almost full most of the time... what a hell... Resizing the partition seems too risky... In that scenario I should probably move all those `ib_data` and `tmp` locations from `/var/mysql` and `/tmp` to the partition `/home` where I have 2To available... But how to do that properly... The best would still be to increase `/dev/root` size, using some space from `/home`, but is there a clean way to do that without physical assistance? What do you suggest?

Comment: [new question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with all information together and better structured.

Comment: changing `tmpdir` location didn't solve the space issue, don't know what `mysql` fills on `/` after the copy. I'm going to try to move `/var/lib/mysql` to `/home`.

Comment: ack. Good. ran out of time to fully consider the resizing options other than this especially on such an old OS.